# How to reduce the gap between label and input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a Bootstrap Form with the label and input field. I would like to know how to reduce the gap between the label and the input field. please check below code and screenshot for your reference

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.FirstName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.LastName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="email" name="EmailId" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId" placeholder="EmailId" value={this.state.EmailId} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

screenshot:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add `pl-0` class to the input parent class and if you want to decrease more gap, you can safely reduce `max-width` of `label` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 pl-0">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.FirstName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 pl-0">
    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.LastName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 pl-0">
    <input type="email" name="EmailId" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId" placeholder="EmailId" value={this.state.EmailId} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!